# mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error: Call to undefined function mbstring_binary_safe_encoding()

Tags: php, wordpress, fatal-error

Since one week I got sometimes a 500 server error in my Wordpress website. I contacted my host and they gave me the following info.

Each time I got a white screen (so the 500 error) the following error was given:

```
mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function mbstring_binary_safe_encoding()
```

Does anyone know what this means and how I can fix this problem? Thanks!

Comment: it's probably to do with a plugin on your wordpress install.

Comment: Okay, but yesterday I unplugged some of the plugin which might cause the problem and I clicked through my site and got still the errors..

Comment: I deleted the plugin now by ftp and I think the problem is solved!

Comment: which plugin was causing the issue?

Comment: This one: http://wordpress.org/plugins/rich-text-tags/screenshots/ and I debugged 2 errors from it yesterday. But for some reason there was still a problem in it.

Answer (score 0):

That is a Wordpress function that is not being included for some reason.

Have you upgraded Wordpress recently or made any other changes?

See this:
https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress/blob/master/wp-includes/functions.php

I suggest you upgrade Wordpress to the latest version and if not, get a clean version of the latest files, re apply your plugins and themes and then point that at your current database

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I think my problem is solved by deleting a plugin from my server.

Comment: Was the plugin listed as compatible with your Wordpress Version?

Comment: Yes! it was compatible

Comment: Something is probably up with your wordpress then, what version are you running?